# jquery class found once removed

Tags: php, jquery, dynamic

I have a complex form that I'm adding things dynamically on.    In part of the script, I'm adding a class based on whether or not there is a score:

```
    var class_name = "form-control score gm"+gm+team;
    if(!score) {
        jQuery("#"+hcp_gm_id).val("0");
        updateGameScratch(gm, team);
        updateGameHandicap(gm, team);
        updateGameTotal(gm, team);
        if(scoreTypeID==2) {
            updateMatchPlayGame(gm, team);
        }
        updateBowlerSeries(pos, team);
        jQuery("#"+scoreID).removeClass();
        jQuery("#"+scoreID).addClass(class_name)
        return;
    }
    score = Number(score);
    var class_name = class_name+" p"+slot+team+"_g"+gm;
    jQuery("#"+scoreID).removeClass();
    jQuery("#"+scoreID).addClass(class_name)
```

This works fine to add/remove the specific score classification.   p#*t*_g*gm* where t is a team abbreviation (v for visitor and h for home) and gm is a specified game number.

If I look within Google Developer Tools, the class will be there if a score is present and will not if the score field is cleared.  So far, so good :-)

However, I later search for this class.  Each class should only have 1 score in it.

```
    teams.forEach(function(team,key){
        for(g=1;g<=games_series;g++) {
            var error = false;
            for(b=1;b<=bowlers_team;b++) {
                var class_name = "p"+b+team+"_g"+g;
                scores = jQuery("."+class_name).length;
console.log("Id:"+class_name+" has "+scores+" scores.\r\n");
                jQuery("."+class_name).each(function () {
                    score_id = this.id;
console.log("Score fields:"+score_id+"\r\n");
console.log("Class Name:"+jQuery("#"+score_id).attr('class')+"\r\n");
                });
```

If I add a score to a field and then remove it, the class is not present in Google Developer Tools but when it goes through the routine - it reports that scores=1 and specifies the id of the score field which was cleared.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.   Note that this fails even on the fields which were not created dynamically.   It clears the class, but it's like the code does not get the updated class information.

Comment: I don't see an obvious cause, but one thing you should improve is your variable declarations. The code is written as if JavaScript has block scope, but it doesn't (if we limit the discussion to JS5). Variables inside a function, should be declared at the start of the function, because that's their actual scope. Also, that variable `scores` is not declared at all with `var` in the code you've shown. In that case, it will be created as a global variable. Also, could you check if you see the problem in all browsers? When it comes to dynamically changing the DOM, IE sometimes behaves differently.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Gert.... I found that before seeing your request and it was causing some tremendous issues with my code.